# Edit Xml InnerText accessed as Plain Text using RegEx?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex, html-agility-pack

I have the following dummy fake sample:

```
<family>
   <member> dad </member>
   <member> mum </member>
   <member> son </member>
   <member> grandad<> </member>
</family>
```

I have been given a document to convert into XML but I have been unsuccessful so far in doing so. I have no control over how the document (html) given to me is created but I need to convert the document to xml; So that I can convert it using a stylesheet.

TidyManaged and HAP are no good to me ***at this stage*** in my workflow. Will explain more if people are interested knowing why.

In order for me to use HAP successfully, I need the above sample to look like the below:

```
<family>
   <member> dad </member>
   <member> mum </member>
   <member> son </member>
   <member> grandad&lt;&gt; </member>
</family>
```

My last approach before I give up on this problem would be, to read in my source html document, treat it as a plan text document and read it line by line.

I require someone to give me some regex that will successfully match the inner text of an element i.e:

```
<member> grandad<> </member>
```

Would give me the string:

```
"grandad<>"
```

If I can get this far, I should be able to convert the angle brackets into html key code equivalents. This should then pass as valid XML allowing me to load this into an XDocument class.

Then replace that result string back with this one:

```
<member> grandad&lt;&gt; </member>
```

When all special characters have been 'escaped' like this properly then I will be in a position to leverage the benefits of HTML Agility Pack (HAP) otherwise I will have to give up.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is there ever anything between the < and the >?  Ie do you have to worry about <member> grandad<randomtext> </member>

Comment: Yeah basically, i dont care what is between the '< some element name >' as they are fine, I care what is between the '> some dodgy<& chars <'

Comment: The reason I am asking is that if you have to handle <member> grandad<Regexp is a bad tool because of <strong>this</strong>> </member>.  Then regexp is not so good.

Comment: Well the dodgy syntax is just angle brackets and ampersands, detecting them and encoding them. All i need is some regex that gets me the inner text of an element when the document is treated a plain text document.

Comment: @acarlon The xml is not well formed, because it either contains tags with no name, or mismatched tags.  So xpath is out.  If you have the possiblity in .net to handle malformed xml on the fly then that would, as I read the problem, be a good solution to the problem - but you would not need to go to xsd for it.

Comment: @Taemyr. I was more thinking of something like this where the offending line number is provided programmatically: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379. I have removed my previous comment because this covers it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest Regular Expressions

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<=<(\w+)>)(.*)(?=</\1>)");
var input = "<member> grandad<Regexp is a bad tool because of <strong>this</strong>> </member>";
var output = reg.Match(input).Value;
```

Problem will be if your `member` tag contains any white spaces or attributes or more then one `member` tag will be in single line. So if you can provide ugliest example I'll change expression to adjust your input.

Comment: Wouldn't eager matching take care of the more than one member tag pr line?  And I think you can change \w+ to [^\>] to handle whitespace/attributes.  (Except if the attribute contains "<>")

Comment: I prefer handle what is needed in regexp. If I use `[^\>]` it will match everything inside angle brackets, so it will be imposible to define exact name for the closing tag

Answer (score -1):

If you can process each document manually then you can use notepad++.

The reindent xml(TextFX->TextFX HTML Tools->Reindent xml> functionality will automatically impose the entities you want.

Comment: Sorry mate, the volume of documents I am talking about is in 6 figures. Using notepad++ is out of the question. THis needs to be some automated pre-cleanup stage before HAP gets its hands on the document. Every single document needs to cleaned up before it can submitted to a workflow for processing.